# Can i use case expressions on both sides of the where clause?

Tags: sql

Like this

```
SELECT *
  FROM UsersMedicalSurgicalHistory UMSH INNER JOIN CCDTransaction CT on                  
                                          UMSH.SurgicalHistoryId = CT.RowId
  WHERE (
         (CASE 
          WHEN LEN(UMSH.DateOfProcedure)<=4 THEN UMSH.DateOfProcedure 
          WHEN LEN(UMSH.DateOfProcedure)=0 THEN UMSH.DateOfProcedure 
          END 
          = 
          CASE WHEN  @CodeFilter3 IS not null THEN @CodeFilter3 
          ELSE UMSH.DateOfProcedure end) 
         OR 
         (CASE 
          WHEN LEN(UMSH.DateOfProcedure)>4 THEN      
              CONVERT(datetime,UMSH.DateOfProcedure,101) 
          ELSE GETDATE() 
          END 
          = 
          CASE WHEN @CodeFilter2 IS not null THEN @CodeFilter2 
          ELSE GETDATE() 
          END)
        )
```

So the question is like CASE expression can be used on both side of WHERE clause

Comment: Format your code.

Comment: I don't think you can do that.

Comment: @pavankumar, you can't compare any random guess with any other random guess... one of the sides must be constant

Comment: @Vikrant  thanks vikrant,please help me understand how it can can be done without using if and else conditions

Comment: @Vikrant i want reduce the no. of statements because the above statement is part of a procedure

Comment: Of course you can use case expressions on both sides. But it's generally not a good idea to have any case expressions at all in the WHERE clause. Stick to AND/OR!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your query is written above...

**CASES** can be minimized to nested conditions as,

```
SELECT * FROM UsersMedicalSurgicalHistory UMSH 
INNER JOIN CCDTransaction CT on UMSH.SurgicalHistoryId = CT.RowId  
WHERE (
        (UMSH.DateOfProcedure = @CodeFilter3 and @CodeFilter3 IS not null)
        OR
        @CodeFilter3 IS null
    )
    OR
    (
        (
            (LEN(UMSH.DateOfProcedure)>4 AND CONVERT(datetime,UMSH.DateOfProcedure,101)=@CodeFilter2)
            OR
            (LEN(UMSH.DateOfProcedure)<=4 AND GETDATE() =@CodeFilter2)
            AND @CodeFilter2 IS NOT NULL
        )
        OR
        (LEN(UMSH.DateOfProcedure)<=4 AND @CodeFilter2 IS null)
    )
```

Try this query... hope it gives desired output :)

Comment: i found the solution with modifications to my logic but it only happened with the above code,thanks a bunch

Comment: you can first upvote my question so i can mark your response answered